# Slower ram in a faster slot?

Tags: memory

Is it possible to put ddr2 533 mhz ram in a ddr2 800 mhz slot along with other ddr2 800mhz dimms? If this does work, will all the ram slow down to 533 mhz, or will they run at their own speed?

Comment: This would slow your 800mhz memory down to 553mhz.  Although its unlikely your motherboard will accept the slower memory since 800mhz is already slower then honey falling out of a honey pot.

Answer (score 2):

Provided the RAM is compatible with the motherboard it should work.

It means that the higher speed ram will be clocked down to 533MHz.

However, it's possible that the mixing of RAM may cause some stability issues.  I've put mixed RAM speeds in a server before and it ran fine however even though the IBM management stuff switched on a light saying there was a problem.

I'm not guaranteeing it'll work perfectly but I have seen mixed RAM speeds work.